# GRAILS run query from custom validator

Tags: grails, stored-procedures, custom-validators

I have domain class like this :

```
class PurchaseOrder {

    String nomor
    Date tanggal
    Supplier supplier

    def dataSource


...
    static constraints = {
        tanggal validator: { val, obj ->
            SimpleDateFormat tempSdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')

            List tempRows = new Sql(dataSource).rows("select max(start_date) as tanggal_saldo_awal from spareparts_bb where start_date <= now()")
            Date tanggalSaldoAwal = null
            if (tempRows != null) {
                tanggalSaldoAwal = tempRows[0].tanggal_saldo_awal
                if (val < tanggalSaldoAwal) {
                    return(['lebihKecilTanggalSaldoAwal', tempSdf(tanggalSaldoAwal)])
                }
            }

        }

}
```

I want to call my stored procedure from my custom validator. But I got this error

**Class:** groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

**Message:** No such property: dataSource for class: com.integra.PurchaseOrder Possible solutions: dataSource

Comment: Use `obj.dataSource` inside the validator because it runs in a static context.

Comment: Nice... worked perfectly... thx a lot... why you dont write your answer on the answer section ? why you post your answer on the comment section ?

Comment: Done. Adding comment was quick when thumb typed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `obj.dataSource` inside validator because it runs in a static context.